# Android studio Barcode read

Tags: java, android, barcode

I'm building an app in android studio to read barcodes and store them into SQL Database. But I want the device to read only certain barcodes and return a false Toast message if the wrong barcode is read. The device I'm using is Symbol TC70. Basically the barcodes that I want the app to read are the SSCC barcodes and if they start with "K02" that would be the wrong barcode, the one that needs to be read starts with "K00" and has 18 digits. I've tried multiple code lines with no success. This is the main code that i started with.

```
private String getSerialnumber() {
    String serialNumber;
    serialNumber = "";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           
            serialNumber = android.os.Build.getSerial();
        } else {
            serialNumber = "Unknown barcode!";
        }
    } else {
        serialNumber = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
    }
    return serialNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try check the return serial number as string like these?

```
private String getSerialnumber() {
String serialNumber;
serialNumber = "";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       
        serialNumber = android.os.Build.getSerial();
        if(!serialNumber.substring(0,4).quals('SSCC'))
            serialNumber = "wrong barcode";
    } else {
        serialNumber = "Unknown barcode!";
    }
} else {
    serialNumber = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
}
return serialNumber;
}
```

Comment: I believe that you meant:

if(!serialNumber.substring(0,4).equals("SSCC"))
            serialNumber = "wrong barcode";

but yeah, i've just tried that aswell, no success again.

Comment: what is the value of the android.os.Build.getSerial() on the right result

Comment: I guess it just returns the string. It works inside the app to fill the text input field with true barcode

Comment: i know it;s return string i want to know how this string look like can you print it in the log and copy it to my?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't connect the device to PC therefore i can't see the log of it's doing. The way I'm checking if the code works is by sending the APK via bluetooth each time i have to make a test of the app.. its a pain.